# Azure VMs /etc/resolve.conf reverts after a reboot

Tags: server, dns, resolv.conf, azure

We have stumbled upon an issue with the Azure 22.04 server LTS VMs

The VMs are on a private network so DNS, gateway, etc.. all preconfigured.

What we need is `ping hostname` to work. and NOT `ping hostname.ourdomain.net`

So on all Ubuntu for years, all we do is edit `/etc/resolv.conf`

which looks like this

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search 4jyx4b3cxcmelah404k3l5mrue.zx.internal.cloudapp.net
```

On the search line we add our search domain like so.

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search ourdomain.net 4jyx4b3cxcmelah404k3l5mrue.zx.internal.cloudapp.net
```

Everything is perfect and it all works 100%

But!!!! With Azure every time we reboot it reverts

To make the change permanent I have tried editing:

```
/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

I have added my domain to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

```
[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
# Google:     8.8.8.8#dns.google 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8844#dns.google
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
Domains=ourdoamin.net
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
#CacheFromLocalhost=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
#DNSStubListenerExtra=
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
```

I have replaced the entire file both `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

```
$ ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Aug 10  2023 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

How do I make this change permanent?